# What is connection between Modules and Fields in mathematics ? Is maybe quotient of the action / space of coinvariants?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, extension-field, isometry, affine-schemes

***Why this question?*** I try to understand  connection between Module & Field more deeply to try to build a particular class of 'fixed points' of non-trivial affine space to 'extract' an affine subspace *isometry*.

This connection that I try to figure out is hard but I accept and propose a challenge
I start from this definition from Wiki

> module over a ring is a generalization of the notion of vector space over a field

So I find that a 'connection' between modules and fields like algebraic structures should be somthing inside definition of *Group Action* $G$: [Spaces of coinvariants](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205324) or maybe an [affine connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection)

also from wiki:

> The group action is transitive if and only if it has exactly one orbit, i.e., if there exists x in X with G⋅x = X. This is the case if and only if G⋅x = X for all x in X.
>   The set of all orbits of X under the action of G is written as X/G (or, less frequently: G\X), and is called the quotient of the action. In geometric situations it may be called the orbit space, while in algebraic situations it may be called the space of coinvariants, and written XG, by contrast with the invariants (fixed points), denoted XG: the coinvariants are a quotient while the invariants are a subset.

I return now on field $\mathbb{F}$ definition

> a field is a set, along with two operations defined on that set

But this definition for me is not useful, it very generical it tells me everything and at the same time nothing

I try to figure out the 'behavior' (behavior = two operations on set) of field  $\mathbb{F}$ to represent same structure in a more open view concept: field $\mathbb{F}$ in terms of hyperplane, isometry plane and [Reflection Relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReflectionRelation.html) between coordinate Space & vector Space 
since the field is the *underlying structure* to build coordinate space into vector space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Module over a ring is nothing else then an abelian group together with a ring action on it. And a field is a special kind of a ring - the one where every non-zero element is invertible. Modules over fields are more widely known as vector spaces.

Comment: I would like to know which relationship, group action, or algebraic structure allows reversibility (compatibility) between modules and fields. If I have a module $M$ , how do I switch to a field $\mathbb{F}$ ? Conversely, if I have a field $\mathbb{F}$, how do I switch into a module $M$ ? What is commutator or how commutation works between modules and fields to switch $M$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{F}$ OR  $\mathbb{F}$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't switch between modules and fields. Apples and oranges. What does it even mean to switch? It's like you would try to switch between, I don't know, cars and shampoo.

Comment: A module *is a ring* [action on an abelian group]. A field *is a ring* [with more axioms]. A ring is a group. Ring action should be a group action. So what ring axioms / group actions is common between modules and fields in order to allow the module to be used in an equivalent way to a field ?

There must be a point where modules and fields are the same thing and in that common point it must then act as a discriminator to differentiate them: I am interested in finding that point.

Comment: Module **cannot** be used in an equivalent to field way. Just like vector space cannot be used like a field. Again: apples and oranges. Field is a ring. Module **is not** a ring.

Comment: Module is a ring *action* (on an abelian group), so if field is a ring and ring is a group (not a group action), what link field and modules at deepest level ?

Comment: there is no deeper link.

Comment: They are different as structures, but as *[actions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action)* should be possible to find a connection! I talk about *action*, not only like structures but in any case both the modules and the fields are constructed using the sets, so if they come from the same 'factory', how is it possible not to identify the function that allows an equivalence as an *action* (not as a structure!)? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action

Comment: **Everything** in mathematics is constructed from sets. Literally everything. Even functions are sets.

Comment: Before there is an *action*, so why talk about *quotient* of action or space of coinvariants ??

Comment: Also *fusion product* should be connected in some way into modules-fields difference, I find something [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196739/concise-mathematical-definition-of-the-fusion-product-on-the-verlinde-ring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally people learn about a field acting on an abelian group first, and they call it a vector space.

If they are lucky, later they learn about rings, and define modules as abelian groups acted upon by rings, and they realize "oh, when the ring is a field, that is just a vector space."

They may also have the opportunity to study an action of a set $X$ on an abelian group (as seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tKq0kbHuc4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=martin+isaacs+algebra+graduate+course+X-group&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIsMPbp8naAhUhp1kKHVUxDHIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Operator%20groups%20and%20unique%20decompositions&f=false)) and that is even more general.

Now, a lot of your post I can't make heads or tails of, but your last sentence makes sense to me, and if that is the most important thing you are asking about I can speak to it:

> .. field  in terms of hyperplane, isometry plane and Reflection Relation between coordinate Space & vector Space since the field is the underlying structure to build coordinate space into vector space.

From this it seems to me you are asking how "field" relates to "geometry," and that, at least, has an interesting answer.

It turns out that given any *division ring* (=a possibly noncommutative field) $D$, $D\times D$ is a Desarguesian plane coordinatized by $D$, satisfying all the usual synthetic axioms of geometry.

The interesting bit is that given any Desarguesian plane (characterized by the synthetic axioms only) *you can build a division ring that coordinatizes it.*  So division rings are precisely the rings that coordinatize Desarguesian planes.

There is a little bit of heuristic sense one can come up with that justifies why division rings are good rings to coordinatize geometries with. For one thing, the fact that every nonzero element is invertible allows you to take any nonzero element in a line through the origin and rescale it to match another nonzero element. Said another way *the multiplicative group of $D$ acts transitively on lines*. For another thing, the axioms for linear subspaces describe pencils of parallel lines (each one has a member going through the origin, and the others are parallels to it.) The abelian group operation allows for translations in the plane.

I think there may be one or two other things to say along those lines, and I'll add them as I recall them, if you turn out to be interested in this discussion.

Comment: @JackyNed Talking about "isometry" moves the question into the realm of bilinear forms, which can be unintuitive for fields other than $\mathbb R$. I'm not sure how I would explain that in terms I began with above.  I don't really follow most of what you're saying in the above four comments. Perhaps if you took some time to focus your ideas and come back with something very specific, we could make progress.

Comment: I remove comments because maybe is off-topic. I return on your answer and I need to understand better when you say "the multiplicative group of D acts transitively on lines".  **1)** for `transitively` you refer about [function transition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitionFunction.html) ? **2)** for `acts` you refer about [group action](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action) ? **3)** when you say `abelian group operation allows for translations in the plane` you describe a way that field relates to geometry, in other words how a field can be geometrized *when it is ring acted* ?

Comment: I don't understand a thing about field because field is a ring but is not the same if I tell 'ring action' but seems to be implicit a field action like ring action because ring is a group and in your answer you talk about an action *"multiplicative group of D **acts***"

Comment: @JackyNed OK, those are all very clear to address. 1) I'm referring to [a transitive group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Transitive)  2) Given the field $F$ and the set $V=F\times F$, ordinary scalar multiplication with vectors defines a map $F\times V\to V$ which I'm describing by **an action of the ring (field) $F$ on (the group) $V$**.  3) Given any $(a,b), (c,d)\in V$, you can find a third element $(x,y)$ such that $(a,b)+(x,y)=(c,d)$: that is, you can translate any point to another. In fact, you can do so uniquely in this case.

Comment: So scalar multiplication is transitive on the nonzero elements of a $1$-d subspace ( a line). If $\langle v\rangle$ is such a subspace, and $w\in \langle v\rangle$, then by definition there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $\lambda v=w$. So you can always go between any two nonzero vectors that are part of the same line.  If we did this for a ring $R$, then there would be no such guarantee.

Comment: mm..thank you.. i I thought it was the action of the group *as a* ring or the action of a group *on a* ring, instead I see now that it is a translation between complement and subject that confused me! so Action of the ring (subject) on group (complement) is correct - I was inverted the order..

Comment: The affine group acts *transitively* on the points of an affine space - maybe can be connected with your sentence ***an action of the ring (field) $F$ on (the group) $V$*** in relation also when you said ***"the multiplicative group of D acts transitively on lines"***. Are there many type of actions for groups, maybe can be a possible connection with isometry that I try to find ? For example when you talk of affine group action you can connect with isometries because
`Isometries are in fact one example of affine group (action)` - [here](https://goo.gl/bkmgqy) you can see this link.

Comment: @JackyNed I think i should say it acts transitively *within* lines rather than “on”.  “Isometry “ implies you are preserving some bilinear form. What form are you talking about?

Comment: mm.. important difference you are highlighting: *within* $\neq$ *on*. Yes, you have hit the point: I search transitively *within* lines like a co-invariance so 'reflection' that I try to find works not an isometry but like a kind of immersion reflection. What mathematically should I need ? I suspect that it is not a *form* I need, but a *function to form* or some kind of action. I take a look for Group cohomology, they say "group cohomology looks at the group actions of a group G in an associated G-module M to elucidate the properties of the group" .But I'm not sure if it's the right direction

Comment: Is possible to *preserving bilinear forms* but not the action ? My idea is to induce a *transition group action* from (not *on* but *within*) same affine group (that acts transitively) within lines to have a kind of translation. Because I think that affine isometry immersion works like a *transation within* so problem is not 'preserving bilinear form' because this is preserved but at same time earn an extra set operation +1 like a specific function.

Comment: I take a look also to Geometry of Hessian Structure in particulary I find **[here](https://books.google.it/books?id=wLPICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=immersion+bilinear+form&source=bl&ots=wzJILfj-Fw&sig=K5fnspbAaebQewm4dEVUgy-ymEQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjir7Tb0MvaAhUKPxQKHc0rBt0Q6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=immersion%20bilinear%20form&f=false)** something that could be useful

Comment: Just last thing: In [affine representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_representation) definition they says *"We may ask whether a given affine representation has a fixed point in the given affine space A"*. [Fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) (is known as an invariant point) of a function is an element of the function's domain that is mapped to itself by the function. But I think that I need to have **co-invariant point** because a coinvariant *is dual* to an invariant so in this way bilinear form is preserved but is like 'domain un-locked'

Comment: @JackyNed sorry, what you are saying is all over the place and I don’t really have anything to add. If you start with an affine space with a metric, then you can always talk about its group of isometrics that acts upon it.

Comment: yes but isometry group of a metric space is the set of all *bijective isometries* (distance-preserving maps) but I need to add $+1$ *operation* like a internal group *action* layer within same isometry group and I think that this $+1$ layer should be a transitive action *from within* same isometry group. Try to figure out so: an action $a$ is just a single cable connection $a$ $\rightarrow$ $A$, a transitive action $t$ is a scheme of cable *connections*  (in math terms *a transitive action is for each pair $x$, $y$ in $X$ there exists a $g$ in $G$ such that $g⋅x = y$*) :

Comment: I need to ***map*** transiction action $t$ (that is a scheme of cable connection) on same transiction action $t$ *remapping* transitive action to obtain a different transition state $t'$ called translation $T$. This is like replace one single plug and insert an electrical socket outlet splitter and then reconnect to this splitter same cable + product cable ($g⋅x = y$) *on it* with correct scheme.