# Generalization of Vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

The Definition of Vector Spaces' operations seems awfully close to Algebraic operations on a Ring. I'm sure there probably is a Generalized version of a Vector space definition using an arbitrary Ring instead of the usual 'additive' $+$  or Scalar ( from $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ) multiplicative ($\lambda$) to a more general Group/Ring Action on a Set? The advantage is then we could study say use the Fundamental Group $\pi(1)$ ( From Algebraic topology) action on Arbitrary sets. Vector Spaces being instances of such spaces as applied to Familiar $\mathbb{R}$ etc. Thanks

Comment: I think what you're looking for are [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics))

Comment: Thanks ! Precisely.. if you could turn it to an answer.. I can accept it.. IMT can then the Vector spaces for Representations in say a Dynkin Quiver be replaced with Modules? Thanks

Comment: No need to turn it into an answer. This has been already done here. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007587/on-two-different-definitons-of-a-module), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909234/in-studying-abstract-algebra-is-vector-space-structure-important), or others.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2745895/242).